# How do I get exact coordinates using iPhone CLLocationManager

Tags: iphone

I am using CLLocationManager *locationManager and getting coordinates but these coordinates are not exact as google map coordinates.

iPhone coordinates are the following
<+26.86126232,+75.75962328>+/-100.00m(speed -1.00 mps/course-1.00)

google map coordinates for same device's location place coordinates are following
<+26.860524,+75.761569>

Google map coordinates are right but iPhone coordinates are wrong these are 100 meter away from  google map's exact coordinates.

How do I get the exact coordinates.

```
 //  MyCLController.h
 //  mapCurrentLocation
 //
 //  Created by mac on 18/11/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
```

//

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  @protocol MyCLControllerDelegate 
  @required
 - (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location;
 - (void)locationError:(NSError *)error;
  @end


@interface MyCLController : NSObject<CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
   IBOutlet UILabel *locationLabel;
CLLocationManager *locationManager; 
id delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;  
@property (nonatomic, assign) id  delegate;
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
 @end



 //
 //  MyCLController.m
 //  mapCurrentLocation
//
//  Created by mac on 18/11/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MyCLController.h"


@implementation MyCLController
@synthesize locationManager;
@synthesize delegate;

- (id) init {
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
    self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self; // send loc updates to myself
}
return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
   // NSLog(@"Location: %@", [newLocation description]);
    [self.delegate locationUpdate:newLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
    [self.delegate locationError:error];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self.locationManager release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end



and here i am using this class--

#import "mapCurrentLocationViewController.h"

@implementation mapCurrentLocationViewController



/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    locationController = [[MyCLController alloc] init];
    locationController.delegate = self;
    [locationController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
    locationLabel.text = [location description];
}

- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error {
    locationLabel.text = [error description];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [locationController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: So how are you getting the coordinates currently? You need to show some code, at least.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
 
 locationController = [[MyCLController alloc] init];
 locationController.delegate = self;
    [locationController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}                                                                   - (void)dealloc {
 [locationController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
    locationLabel.text = [location description];
}

- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error {
    locationLabel.text = [error description];
}

Comment: in MyCLController class i am defining delegates <CLLocationManagerDelegate> and creating object of CLLocationManager *locationManager.                                                      This class is taken from example.

Comment: Edit your post and use the code tags to paste the code in, it's very difficult to read it in the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

To get the most accurate possible location measurements, set `locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;` before you `startUpdatingLocation`.

Also, check the `timestamp` and `horizontalAccuracy` of the `CLLocation` objects that get delivered to `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`.  If the location measurement seems like it's older or less accurate than you'd like, set a timer and wait for some more location measurements to be delivered.  Core Location will often deliver a cached and/or imprecise location quickly, and then follow up with refined location measurements that are more accurate.